# Рекурсия массивов в php

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работает рекурсия, и как написать такую функцию, чтоб она могла проходить по всему массиву и удалить определённый элемент. 
Или просто дайте, пожалуйста, пример такой функции. Остальное я сам сделаю, я не могу понять, как это должно работать. 
Спасибо.

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => text
                    [1] => created_ad
                )

            [1] => required
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => id_user
                    [1] => priority
                    [2] => status
                    [3] => created_ad
                )

            [1] => integer
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => text
                    [1] => img
                )

            [1] => string
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => id_user
            [1] => safe
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => priority
            [1] => default
            [value] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => status
            [1] => default
            [value] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => priority
            [1] => in
            [range] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 2
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => status
            [1] => in
            [range] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

Из этого массива нужно удалить id_user и created_ad

```
private function unsetRules($rules = null)
{
    foreach ($rules as $key => &$rule) {

        if (is_array($rules[$key])) {
            $this->unsetRules($rules[$key]);
        }

        if ($rules[$key] === 'id_user') {
            unset($rules[$key]);

        }
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Вот так ничего не выходит=(

Comment: А как выглядит сам масив примерно?

Comment: @Naumov Добавил массив

Comment: Все, что вам надо, это вот это http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Answer (score 2):

```
private function unsetRules(&$array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $this->unsetRules($value);
        } else {
            if (in_array($array[$key], $this->deleteRules())) {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Все получается довольно просто, нужно было использовать массив по ссылке

Answer (score -1):

Наверное, так:

```
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
    if ($array[$i] == 0) {
        unset($array[$i]);
    }
}
```

Только каким боком тут рекурсия?

Comment: наверное должно быть в функции условие `if (is_array($value)) { запускать новый круг функции со входным параметром $value;  }`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Парни )) Наверное стоит у автора вопроса спросить какой массив как минимум :D

Answer (score -1):

Рекурсивная функция обращается сама к себе, при необходимости и выполняет проверку по новым элементам, пример проверки элементов по рекурсией по вложенным объектам:

```
// рекурсивная функция проверки
function arrayChecking(array $some_array){

    foreach ($some_array as $key=>$value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            arrayChecking($value); // здесь рекурсивный вызов функцией самой себя, с новым вложенным массивом, когда функция закончит его обрабатывать, она вернется к месту прерывания и продолжит работу с родительским массивом и т.д. 
        }

        if($value == "ваше значение"){
            // ваше действие
        }
    }    
}

$array_for_checkig = array();

arrayChecking($array_for_checkig);
```

Как удалить рекурсией не подскажу. Нужно додумать. 
Если нужно удалить элемент массива по значению, то в простом массиве делается следующим образом:

```
$array = array('key1' => 'Item 1', 'key2' => 'Item 2','Key3' => 'Всякая фигня');
if(($key = array_search('Всякая фигня',$array)) !== FALSE){
     unset($array[$key]);
}
```

Comment: хорошо бы добавить, что в целом код написанный выше повторяет [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Comment: а для удаления массив в функцию по ссылке передавать надо, а удалять все также через `unset()`